# error: expected initializer before ‘std’

Tags: c++, std

```
anisha@linux-trra:~> make
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -I/usr/lib64/R/include -I/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include -I/usr/lib64/R/library/RInside/include -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I/home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include/QtCore -I/home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include/QtGui -I/home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/include -I. -o zoomCornerPanDatabaseParser.o zoomCornerPanDatabaseParser.cpp
In file included from zoomCornerPanDatabaseParser.h:9:0,
                 from zoomCornerPanDatabaseParser.cpp:1:
*******************boundaryLineEquation.cpp:6:1: error: expected initializer before ‘std’
make: *** [zoomCornerPanDatabaseParser.o] Error 1
```

The `.cpp`:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include "boundaryLineEquation.h"

/// This function will return the direction of the new point as w.r.t to the given rectangle.
********************std :: string findPanDirection (float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float newX, float newY)
{
    if (x1 > x2)
    {
        float temp = x1;
        x1 =x2;
        x2 = temp;
    }

    if (y2 > y1)
    {
        float temp = y2;
        y2 = y1;
        y1 = temp;
    }

    if (newX < x1 )
    {
```

The `.h`:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifndef RLINE
#define RLINE

std :: string findPanDirection (float x1, float y1, 
                        float x2, float y2, 
                        float newX, float newY);

bool returnDistance (float centerPointLng, float centerPointLat, 
                float newCenterPointLng, float newCenterPointLat)

#endif
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Missing `;` from `returnDistance()` declaration. Should be:

```
bool returnDistance (float centerPointLng, float centerPointLat, 
                     float newCenterPointLng, float newCenterPointLat);
                                                                    //^
```

Comment: Now isn't that "ridiculous"!! How exactly was I supposed to guess that from this error? Thanks, BTW.

Comment: @AnishaKaul A good hint would be that if you don't find an error on the line referenced by the compiler, then look at the lines preceding the referenced line. In your case it's an `#include` which means you should look into the included header file. In C++ (and in C) an error in one line can lead to another error being reported much later (e.g. missing parentheses or braces).

Answer (score 2):

You need a semi-colon

```
bool returnDistance (float centerPointLng, float centerPointLat, 
                     float newCenterPointLng, float newCenterPointLat);
                                                                      ^
```

Comment: Yes, the other person has already answered. Thanks to you too.